# how to get the youtube video id

Tags: web-scraping, youtube

i thought that the video id of a video was what was after `watch?v` so for the video see you again `RgKAFK5djSk`
but when i use this API to find the thumbnail of a video it doesn't work
`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<RgKAFK5djSk>/maxresdefault.jpg` when on this forum they say to only put the video id [How to scrape the thumbnail of a youtube video from id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297204/how-to-scrape-the-thumbnail-of-a-youtube-video-from-id) so if it doesn't works it because the id is not good when on the api i just need to  put the id, if not that what's the error on the link after all it's true that if the id is not that what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to use angular brackets around Video ID.

Correct Link:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/RgKAFK5djSk/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: ah ok thanks, it wasn't the id that was wrong, thanks.