# How to scrape 10k records per day from youtube using google API

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-api

I am using Google api to scrape data from YouTube using YouTube v3. Based on search keyword I am trying to scrape the data like `likescount`, `viewscount`, `dislikescount` etc.

The problem is by default we are able to get up to 50 records. I need to get more records and we can achieve that by using pagination.

In January 11 2019 Google has decreased from 1M records to 10K per day. To request 10k record per day we need to do pagination and I am not sure how to set the pagination in my code.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import argparse
import csv
import unidecode

DEVELOPER_KEY = "xxxxxxx"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
    
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    
    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=options.q,part="id,snippet",maxResults=options.max_results).execute()
    
    videos = []
    channels = []
    playlists = []
    
    csvFile = open('checking_for_no_of_records.csv','w')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(["title","videoId","viewCount","likeCount","dislikeCount", "commentCount","favoriteCount"])

    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            title = search_result["snippet"]["title"]
            title = unidecode.unidecode(title)
            videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"]
            video_response = youtube.videos().list(id=videoId,part="statistics").execute()
            for video_result in video_response.get("items",[]):
                    viewCount = video_result["statistics"]["viewCount"]
                    if 'likeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                            likeCount = 0
                    else:
                            likeCount = video_result["statistics"]["likeCount"]
                    if 'dislikeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                            dislikeCount = 0
                    else:
                            dislikeCount = video_result["statistics"]["dislikeCount"]
                    if 'commentCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                            commentCount = 0
                    else:
                            commentCount = video_result["statistics"]["commentCount"]
                    if 'favoriteCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                            favoriteCount = 0
                    else:
                            favoriteCount = video_result["statistics"]["favoriteCount"]
            csvWriter.writerow([title,videoId,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount, commentCount,favoriteCount])

    csvFile.close()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--q', help='Search term', default='Google')
  parser.add_argument('--max-results', help='Max results',default = 50)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  youtube_search(args)
```

With this above code I'm able to get only 50 records, but I need to get 10K records per day.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest to achieve this 10K records perday

Comment: @jezrael, do you have any idea about this query. Thanks

Comment: No one faced this issue yet?

Comment: There is no proper document to follow to increase the size of scraping the records from youtube using google API

Comment: @Gajendra D Ambi I have gone through your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512239/python-get-all-youtube-video-urls-of-a-channel/24236857 kindly please do let me know how can I get all the videos url which is available in that channel

Comment: @Gajendra D Ambi it is only giving limited video url's not all the videos